# Shared lib folder only among specific hosts of tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am working with **apach-tomcat-7.0.67**, having 3 different hosts and appBase configuration in server.xml file, **webappsA**, **webappsB** and **webappsC** in tomcat instead of only one webapps. I would like to share external lib folder of jar with only **webappsB** and **webappsC**. webappsA will not get shared lib.

if i do configuration at *catalina.properties* by setting **shared.loader=/home/amjad/shared_lib/*.jar**, then shared_lib available to 3 webapps. But i don't want for webappsA. How can i do this.